# make magic suggestion in bootstrap faster

Tags: performance, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, magicsuggest

i used magic Suggest in bootstrap to auto complete search.
but now i want to become faster it.
i have many data, so i cached data from database to access data faster with out querying in database.
my source-URL is a spring-MVC controller that return data as a json type.
but i want to see result of search faster.how can i do this with magic suggest??

i think because of having many data.it is slow.
for example when i write 'm' in textBox it is slow to suggest data,and some times browser hanging.

Answer (score 1):

set **max suggestion** minimal Integer, in magic suggestion. help me to improve performance.
before that i show all of the items in one time and it make my system slow.
now when set **max suggestion=10;** improve suggestion performance.